# How to use sed / awk / grep … to extract blocks from a file and each block save it into a file

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, awk

Good day to all,

In this opportunity, I'm trying to find a bash code that allow me to extract text blocks between the same pattern and each block save to a different file.

*My first approach is*:

**sed -n "/PATTERN/,/PATTERN/p" file.log**

{...and yes, into the log file, the pattern that delimit each block is the same}

But it only print all blocks in one stream... I want to save each block into a file. But, I don't know how to make a stop in each block, save it and continue with the following block.

Thanks so much in advance for any help.

`
PATTERN

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

PATTERN

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

PATTERN

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
```

`

Comment: So, you want to take out multiple blocks of text from the same file and save them to different files? And these blocks are already pre-defined and are separated by some PATTERN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should create files named `resultNUM` where `NUM` is a number of the block

```
awk '/PATTERN/{close("result"f);f++}{print $0 > "result"f}' file.log
```

Comment: I would have removed the word PATTERN and blank lines in the printout like this : `awk '/PATTERN/{close("result"f);f++} !/PATTERN|^$/{print $0 > "result"f}' file.log`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
csplit -z file '/PATTERN/' '{*}'
```